# How to target the last of type visible element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I need some help I have a drupal webform in which new form elements show conditionally if the previous text input has content.

What I’m trying to do is select all inputs that are currently visible and then specifically target the last one (the most recently shown).

The issue is this targets the last child within each .form-item rather than the last form item itself directly.

```js
$(".webform").on("change", function() {
  $(".form-item:visible").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":last-of-type")) {
      //Do whatever
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="webform">
  <div class="form-item" style="display:block">
  </div>
  <div class="form-item" style="display:block">
  </div>
  <div class="form-item" style="display:block">
  </div>
  <div class="form-item" style="display:none">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed your invalid code (brackets) AND HTML (backslash) and made a snippet.

Comment: What "change" are you expecting? Show more code please. Add inputs in a [mcve]

Comment: `$('.webform .form-item:visible:last').text()` . this is what you needed

Comment: So sorry I’m writing this on a mobile on a train on my way to work so it may not have been as pretty as it could have been but thank you so much

Comment: @user2983251  `$(".webform").on("change", function() {` will not work here.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your flow by using this [jQuery:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector

```
$('.form-item:visible:last')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may apply the below code on form field change or form submit, depending on your requirements.

```
<div class="webform">
    <div class="form-item" style="display:block">
        <input type="text" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item" style="display:block">
        <input type="text" value="2" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item" style="display:block">
        <input type="text" value="3" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item" style="display:none">
        <input type="text" value="4" />
    </div>
</div>

<script>alert($(".form-item:visible:last input").val());</script>
```